# SQL Sub query questions

Tags: sql

My directions are: "Devise a list of course names that are offered in the fall semester in rooms where the capacity is equal to or above the average room size."

I have gotten to where I need to calculate the average room size and compare it, but i'm unsure how to do that with what ive got.

http://pastebin.com/1VpFYaHS

My Tables:

http://s24.postimg.org/oldhbkvnp/Capture.png

Comment: For these types of questions, [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) is great.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery in SQL is fairly easy.  You have noncorrelated subqueries and correlated subqueries.  Noncorrelated means they can be run independently.   Correlated means it is dependent on the main query.

To give you a simplified example of what you are after without giving you the full answer, so you can learn some yourself, you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM Course WHERE Capacity >= (SELECT AVG(Capacity) FROM Room)
```

Of course, you need to fill in the query with the appropriate columns you need to retrieve and the joins (for Course Number and Room), but the main part is `Capacity >= (SELECT AVG(Capacity) FROM Room)` where `SELECT AVG(Capacity) FROM Room` is a noncorrelated subquery and you are comparing the Capacity of each row to the AVG(Capacity) of that query.